# Value not overriding in ArrayList for same index

Tags: java

I'm trying example of List implementation. In ArrayList Java has **add("index","value")**.

Whenever I'm inserting same index on different value, It won't overriding that index instead of it adjusting with next index;

```
    list.add(0, 8);
    list.add(1, 18);
    list.add(1, 28);
    list.add(1, 38);
    System.out.println(list);
```

OP : `[8, 38, 28, 18]`

What happening here in this.?

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [API for java.util.ArrayList.add()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)):

> public void add(int index,
>          E element)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   **Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).**

If you want to override an element at a given index try using [ArrayList.set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

as specified in the doc, add insert to specified position and shifts others.

> Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.
>   Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

You should use `ArrayList#set` instead of `ArrayList#add` to replace values.

**ArrayList#set:**

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the
>   specified element.

here is the codes:

```
    list.add(0, 8);
    list.add(1, 18);
    list.set(1, 28);
    list.set(1, 38);
    System.out.println(list);
```

Output :  `[8, 38]`

**See Also:**

**[ArrayList#Add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E))**

**[ArrayList#Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E))**